# Finding derivative and getting desired result.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

hello everybody I am trying to solve this problem. I am finding the derivative w.r.t. $x_{o}$ of following expression.
$$\alpha(x_{o})=2\int^{\infty}_{x_{o}}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{\bigg(\frac{x}{x_{o}}\bigg)^{2}\Big(1-\frac{1}{x_{o}}\Big)-
  \Big(1-\frac{1}{x}\Big)}}-\pi.$$

I have to follow the steps given in research paper. I tried this approach

$$\frac{d\alpha}{d\theta}= \frac{d\alpha}{dx_{o}}.\frac{dx_{o}}{d\theta}.$$

I am ok with my first result which is following.

$$\frac{dx_{o}}{d\theta}=\frac{x_{o}(1-\frac{1}{x_{o}})^{\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{1-(\frac{2M}{d_{ol}})^{2}x_{o}^{}(1-\frac{1}{X_{o}})^{-1}}}
  {\frac{M}{d_{ol}}(2x_{o}-3)}.$$

But I can not reach this result.

$$ \frac{d\alpha}{dx_{o}}= \frac{3-2x_{o}}{x_{o}^{2}(1-\frac{1}{x_{o}})} \int^{\infty}_{x_{o}}\frac{(4x-3)dx}{(3-2x)^{2}x\sqrt{\bigg(\frac{x}{x_{o}}\bigg)^{2}\Big(1-\frac{1}{x_{o}}\Big)-
  \Big(1-\frac{1}{x}\Big)}}
$$